# Is there an event that is fired when the map is done rendering?

Tags: javascript, mapbox-gl

I am looking for an event that is fired on `zoomend` AND/OR `moveend`.
 Basically I have a popup that needs to happen after either of these events, and that popup depends on queryRenderedFeatures, which can only be queried if they are in the map view.

I am currently using a `setTimeout` function if there is not `zoomend`, but this is not ideal.
 Yes, I can attach functions after both of these, but this get messy.
 I see there is a `map.on('data')` event, but is there a `map.on('data.load')` or something similar, like on `map.on('style.load')`?

What I am wanting is something that is fired after there is no longer any `map.on('data')` events firing. Maybe this can be done in Javascript with `setInterval` or something.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can bind your query function to `map.on('move', function() {})` which will fire continuously as the map is being zoomed or dragged.

In my application, I use `map.on('move', function() {})` to get the center lat/lng of the map. So my code roughly looks like this:

```
setCenter () {
  const center = map.getCenter()
  // render the center coords
}

// later in my code
map.on('move', this.setCenter)

// and when I'm done
map.off('move', this.setCenter)
```

Comment: If you do `map.on('data', function() {console.log('test')});` you will see that when you move the map, there is a series of data requests, then they stop. I am wondering if there is an event that is fired when there are no more data requests. Alternately, I wonder if there is a way to tell in javascript when an event is not fired say for a period of one second.

Comment: The `.on('move')` function will not tell you if the map is rendered.

Comment: @malcolm I know the post is old, just an fyi and for others, to determine when an event is not fired, " tell in javascript when an event is not fired say for a period of one second"
1: in the event handler set a timer to start (not the best approach),  reset it at each new event OR 
2: set datetimevalue for firedLast from with in your event and you could check that with current dateTime from other methods etc.